# table style KeyError: u"no style with name 'Table Grid'"

Tags: python, python-docx

I trying to insert a table via python-docx but it give the error 
code is:

```
#-*-coding:utf-8-*-
import re 
import time
import datetime
import sys
import os
import csv
from docx import Document
import docx
from docx import *  
from docx.oxml import OxmlElement
from docx.oxml.ns import qn
from docx import Document
from docx.shared import Inches
from docx.enum.text import WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH
from docx.shared import Pt
from docx.shared import Cm
from docx import section
from docx.enum.table import WD_TABLE_ALIGNMENT
import win32com.client

lastday=str(datetime.date.today()-datetime.timedelta(days=1))

CURRENT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(sys.argv[0]))

docxFilePath = os.path.join(CURRENT_DIR,'logsample.docx')
doc=Document(docxFilePath)



def buildtable():


    #id_numbers=sum(1 for row in idlist)

    table = doc.add_table(rows = 3, cols = 2)


    table.alignment = WD_TABLE_ALIGNMENT.CENTER
    table.style = 'Table Grid'







buildtable()
```

it always gives me error is :

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\Robin-work-laptop\Desktop\New folder\log\makereport.py",
>   line 49, in 
>       buildtable()   File "C:\Users\Robin-work-laptop\Desktop\New folder\log\makereport.py", line 41, in buildtable
>       table.style = 'Table Grid'   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\docx\table.py", line 134, in style
>       style_or_name, WD_STYLE_TYPE.TABLE   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\docx\parts\document.py", line 76, in
>   get_style_id
>       return self.styles.get_style_id(style_or_name, style_type)   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\docx\styles\styles.py", line 113, in
>   get_style_id
>       return self._get_style_id_from_name(style_or_name, style_type)   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\docx\styles\styles.py", line 143,
>   in _get_style_id_from_name
>       return self._get_style_id_from_style(self[style_name], style_type)   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\docx\styles\styles.py", line 57,
>   in **getitem**
>       raise KeyError("no style with name '%s'" % key) KeyError: u"no style with name 'Table Grid'"

Please help I read the documnets the style is in the list as Table Grid

Comment: Python seems to disagree, it can obviously not work with 'Table Grid'. Maybe a type? Also, you should really fix your imports, there are numerous duplicates in there...

Answer (score 2):

Your document does not have the 'Table Grid' style defined in it. The styles that appear to be "built-in" in Word are actually not added to the document until the first time they are used.

You can learn more about the behavior of these so-called "latent styles" by reading the related part of the `python-pptx` documentation here:
http://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/styles-understanding.html
and here:
http://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/styles-using.html

Comment: but when check the xml it has Table Grid like :<w:lsdException w:name="Table Grid" w:semiHidden="0" w:uiPriority="59" w:unhideWhenUsed="0"/>

Comment: I tried add: styles = doc.styles
style = styles.add_style('Table Grid', WD_STYLE_TYPE.TABLE) but the table not appears the style.

Comment: The `w:lsdException` element is part of a latent style definition (not an _actual_ style definition). The documentation I linked to can help you understand that distinction. A table style can only be added using Word, not `python-pptx` (yet anyway). The documentation I linked to also explains that.

Comment: @scanny: I can fix the issue by referring to https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx/issues/504. Thanks.