# Python: KeyError: "no style with name 'Quote Char'"

Tags: python, styles, python-docx

(Python 3.7, python-docx 0.8.6)

Recently, I am learning Python about python-docx from a website. The URL of the website is https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter13/. One error appears when I run the following codes.

```
import docx, os
os.chdir('C:\\')

doc = docx.Document('demo.docx')
doc.paragraphs[1].runs[0].style = 'Quote Char'
```

The error reads： KeyError: "no style with name 'Quote Char'"
   I found someone has the same question, the URL is：[table style KeyError: u"no style with name 'Table Grid'"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50687678/table-style-keyerror-uno-style-with-name-table-grid)

I look through the python-docx documentation (http://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/styles-understanding.html), and I found the 'Quote Char' does exist in (Character styles in default template).

Besides, The python-docx 0.8.6 documentation mentions: Although those styles show up in the UI, they’re not actually in the document you’re creating, at least not until you use it for the first time.

So I have two questions:

(1)   Does the character style “Quote Char” exists in the built-in styles. If Yes, how to use the style “Quote Char” for the first time?

(2)   I could not understand so-called latent styles. What is the difference between built-in styles and latent styles?

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 2):

In Word, there are a lot of built-in styles you can pick from without having to define them. These are called *latent* styles because they are not defined in the document until first used. Each such style is *latent* in the document until used, at which point it becomes *explicitly defined* in the document. This prevents a lot of unused styles from adding to the document file size, while allowing user to pick from a coherent set of styles without having to actually define any of them in detail.

The actual definition of a latent style is performed by the Word application the first time the style is used. `python-docx` on the other hand, can only use styles that are actually defined; it cannot add one of these latent styles to the document the way Word can.

So if you want to use a style called "Quote Char", either use Word to add it to the document before opening it with `python-docx`, or use the `python-docx` styles API to define it yourself before attempting to use it.

If you add a paragraph and assign it a latent style, that style is added to the document. However, when  you delete that paragraph, the style remains. Once explicitly defined, a style is never removed automatically by Word. This is the easiest way to get an explicitly-defined version of a latent style in your document.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You said that if I want to use a style called "Quote Char", I should use Word to add it to the document before opening it with python-docx. Now my question is, I can use the Paragraph style named "Quote" in Python. Besides, in my Word software, the style named "Quote"  could be applied to both Paragraph and Character. After I used "Quote" style in Word. The error still exist.